# How to add a column at the end of .txt file in Linux?

Tags: linux, awk, addition

I want to add a new column containing only '2' as a value in each row at the end of the a .txt file and save new file as output. I saved my input.txt file from R as a tab separated file. I have tried the following code;

`awk -v RS='\r\n' 'BEGIN {OFS = '\t'} {print $0, "2"}' input.txt > output.txt`

but it adds 2 as an additional value to the last column and also adds a blank row after every data row in the output.txt file

my input.txt

```
SAMPLE  rs1     rs2     rs3     rs4     rs5     rs6     rs7     rs8     rs9     rs10    rs11
6       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
7       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
10                                                      1                       1       
14      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
19      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
34      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
40                                                              1               1       1
41      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
46                                                                              1       
58                                                                              1       
67      0       0       0       0       0       0               0       0       0       0
69                                                                              1       
71      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
76      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
78      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
80                                                                              1       
83      0       0       0       0       0       0               0       0       0       0
84                                                                              1       
86                                                                              1       
90                                                                              1       
92      0       0       0       0       0       0               0       0       0       0
94      0       0       0       0       0       0               0       0       0       0
95      0       0       0       0       0       0               0       0       0       0
```

what I am getting as output.txt using above code;

```
SAMPLE  rs1     rs2     rs3     rs4     rs5     rs6     rs7     rs8     rs9     rs10    rs112

6       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       02

7       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       02

10                                                      1                       1       2

14      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       02

19      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       02

34      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       02

40                                                              1               1       12

41      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       02

46                                                                              1       2

58                                                                              1       2

67      0       0       0       0       0       0               0       0       0       02

69                                                                              1       2

71      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       02

76      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       02

78      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       02

80                                                                              1       2

83      0       0       0       0       0       0               0       0       0       02

84                                                                              1       2

86                                                                              1       2

90                                                                              1       2

92      0       0       0       0       0       0               0       0       0       02

94      0       0       0       0       0       0               0       0       0       02

95      0       0       0       0       0       0               0       0       0       02
```

How do add a column of 2s at the end? Also, is there a way to add a header to (e.g., extra) this column in the output.txt file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want sed:

```
$ t=$(printf '\t')
$ sed -e '1s/$/'"${t}header/" -e '1!s/$/'"${t}2/" input > output
```

Comment: It is working right but adding ^M to the 'rs11' column `SAMPLE  rs1     rs2     rs3     rs4     rs5     rs6     rs7     rs8     rs9     rs10    rs11^M  header
6       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0^M     2
7       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0^M     2
10                                                      1                       1       ^M      2`     How do I get rid of ^M from second last column (rs11) in output.txt file?

Comment: IMO, you should convert the input file to unix line endings before doing anything.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
$ awk -v RS='\r\n' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {print $0, (NR==1?"header":2)}' input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: The code adds the column and header right, but it is still adding an extra blank row after every data row in the file. How do I get rid of those blank rows?

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk. WIth other awks it'll just use `\r` as the RS and print the subsequent `\n` as the start of the next record.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you aren't using GNU awk so `RS='\r\n'` is being treated as just `RS='\r'` thus leaving the newline as part of the next record. Also the `'BEGIN {OFS = '\t'} ... '` in your script would have set `OFS` to the null string since it'd be trying to use the contents of an uninitialized awk variable named `t` - count the `'`s to see that the `\t` is outside of the awk program.

Try this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} {sub(/\r$/,""); print $0, (NR>1 ? 2 : "header")}' input.txt > output.txt
```

The above will work using any awk in any shell on every UNIX system whether your lines end in `\r\n` or just `\n`.